# JSON not working for javascript Variable

Tags: json

HELP this is driving me insane:

I have routeMapping varible containing this:

```
{"b":[{"Ya":53.388639,"Za":-1.4785248000000593},{"Ya":53.39310538272831,"Za":-1.464529037475586}],"gm_accessors_":{"length":null},"length":2,"gm_bindings_":{"length":{}}}
```

this works

```
alert('length is ' + (routeMapping.length -1))
```

so does this:

```
alert(routeMapping);
```

but not this!:

```
alert(routeMapping.b[1].Ya);
```

please help

Comment: And `i` value is? Is `i` value is valid index for `b` array?

Comment: I have noticed that your json is not valid, its missing a trailing } assuming its just a copy/paste error, but please confirm.

Comment: Run your json through here: http://jsonlint.com/ and see the results.

Comment: @Nix yes sorry, ive edited it as per

Comment: @GrzegorzGierlik sorry, that is from an array, I was supposed to put 1

Comment: @ToddMurray it says it valid. Good tool though

Comment: google browser is saying Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Comment: It works fine for me.  Can you show how you set `routeMapping`

Comment: function mapRoute(showPosition3, position){
        var routeCoordinates = [new google.maps.LatLng(latStart, lonStart )];
        var polyOptions = {
        path: routeCoordinates,
        strokeColor: "#0000ff",
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
    }
    flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
    flightPath.setMap(map);
 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() 
{
var path = flightPath.getPath();
center = map.getCenter();
path.push(center);
var lastpos = path;  
routeMapping = JSON.stringify(lastpos);
//alert(routeMapping);

});

}

Comment: Are you seeing ant javascript errors?  It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/V9cRP/.  Prolly you just want:  routeMapping = lastpos;  Get rid of the JSON.stringify().

Comment: You've cracked it @ToddMurray Nice one!

Answer (score 0):

What is the execution context?

I just tried this on the console on chrome and it worked perfectly.

I did

```
var x = eval("(" + '{"b":[{"Ya":53.388639,"Za":-1.4785248000000593},{"Ya":53.39310538272831,"Za":-1.464529037475586}],"gm_accessors_":{"length":null},"length":2,"gm_bindings_":{"length":{}}}' + ")")
```

and then

```
 x.b[1].Ya
```

and it showed me 53.38... as expected I think

-ace